# Query with Chinese values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a simple SQL statement with Chinese values but it doesn't work. I fund from MSD forums that I must use an **nvarchar** field in my **MS SQL Server**, but it doesn’t work either.

This is a code extract:

```
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
sqlCommand.CommandText = "insert into ExampleTable values('发现','发现','发现')"
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is executed without problem, but in the DataBase I got this: "???????????????????"

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Use placeholders .. makes life easier, safer, and most likely "fixes" this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preceed the values with the letter N to treat them as `nvarchar`:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "insert into ExampleTable values(N'发现',N'发现',N'发现')"
```

Comment: Hey Little Bobby. Can you do SQL Injection in Chinese?

Comment: By way of explanation, adding an N to a constant tells SQL Server to consider it an NVARCHAR constant rather than a VARCHAR.